# Modifying a MySQL Query that Removes Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY date DESC) AS p
GROUP BY first_name,last_name,work_phone
```

If you hadn't figured it out already, this removes entries with duplicate names and work phone numbers, leaving only the most recent. There is another field in the person table you should know about, a binary field called DELETED.

The problem is, if there is a duplicate of this nature, I don't want a row to be considered if its DELETED value is TRUE regardless of how recent its date value is. However, if a row has no duplicates it should be included in the results no matter what DELETED value it has.

If duplicates exist there is never a case where all duplicates have DELETED = TRUE, at least one will not be deleted.

Comment: Does the SQL you've posted actually run? I would expect it to complain because `SELECT *` includes fields not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Don, it does run in MySQL, you are talking about MSSQL, PostgreSQL or that stuff.

Comment: Yes, the query runs fine, I am using it currently.

Comment: I see that now. Here's an article discussing [MySQL GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM   
  (SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY deleted ASC, date DESC) AS p
GROUP BY first_name,last_name,work_phone
```

Comment: According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), it looks like this query is legal, but the results are indeterminate. Is it a good idea to rely on the current implementation of MySQL's grouping?

Comment: @Don, yes it is. You can disable this so called implementation detail with a server setting, but it's part of MySQL and it's not going away.

Comment: @Don and the result of **this** query is not indeterminate.

Comment: The way I read the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), @Johan, this query is indeterminate. The docs say that if the values for a column are not all the same for a group, then the selected value is indeterminate. For example, if there is a `persons.office` column and a person has two records with different offices but the same names and phone number, then the office field will be indeterminate.

Comment: @Don, the inner query runs first and sorts its resultset. After that the outer query is no longer indeterminate. This is because field date is a unique field in this table, per the OP's specs. If date is **not** unique then yes it would be indeterminate.

Comment: @Don, got an article 'bout this you might like: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html  Although I'm not sure the inner select order by, group by in outer select case is handled there.

Comment: Thanks, @Johan, I found that article this morning when I started trying to understand this funky behaviour. From the conclusion of that article: "In MySQL, one can write GROUP BY queries that reference non-aggregated columns in the SELECT list that are not included in the GROUP BY clause, even if these columns are not functionally dependent upon the GROUP BY clause. This behaviour conforms to none of the SQL standard's versions." Nowhere in that article or the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) did I see any mention of the sorting trick you use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand the problem:

1. You have a `persons` table with fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `work_phone`, `deleted`, and a bunch of others.
2. Any records that have the same first and last name, as well as work phone should be considered duplicates.
3. The most recent undeleted duplicate should be used, or just the most recent if they've all been deleted.

Here's a rough sketch of how I would approach the problem:

1. Select the distinct first_name, last_name, and work_phone values in a subquery.
2. Left join that to the most recent undeleted record for each combination in another subquery.
3. Left join that to the most recent record for each combination in a third subquery.
4. Use `coalesce` to pull out the values from the second or third subquery, whichever is not null..